# Update column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

All data in column foo are suffixed by a `_`. I want to delete this `_`.  Can I do it using SQL rather than writing a script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few ways to do it:

- [`TRIM`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) the trailing '_':

  ```
  UPDATE mytable
  SET foo = TRIM(TRAILING '_' FROM foo)
  ```
- Grab the substring consisting of characters 1 to *n*-1, *n* being the length of the string in `foo`, using [`SUBSTRING`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) and [`CHAR_LENGTH`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length):

  ```
  UPDATE mytable
  SET foo = SUBSTRING(foo,1,CHAR_LENGTH(foo)-1)
  ```

I'd recommend the first method as, if you have, say, one row in `foo` that *doesn't* end in '_', the first method will leave it as is, whereas the second will take of its last character even though that isn't an underscore.

Answer (score 0):

Sure:

```
SELECT TRIM( TRAILING '_' FROM foo ) AS foo FROM ... ;
```

([Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim))

Comment: I believe you was on right track, but you are trying to display and OP wanted to `UPDATE`.

Comment: @FahimParkar I figured it was illustrative enough that the OP could put two and two together.